# SNMP object not in the MIB

Tags: switch, router, snmp, management, dell

i'm working on an SNMP app that needs the [ptopo MIB object](http://cric.grenoble.cnrs.fr/Administrateurs/Outils/MIBS/?oid=1.3.6.1.2.1.79) with the object ID of 1.3.6.1.2.1.79

after enabling SNMP v3 on 2 layer 3 switches

- dell z9100-on
- brocade slx 9140

and creating a view on the whole MIB (with OID = 1) `snmp-server view allAccess 1 included` and giving my user access to that

i used the linux command `snmpwalk` and `snmpget`, **but i cannot find the OID 1.3.6.1.2.1.79** i get the output `iso.3.6.1.2.1.79 = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID`

so my question is

- is it possible to add support for an OID that is not there by default?
- if yes, then how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is it possible to add support for an OID that is not there by default?

Unfortunately, adding support for these OIDs would require each of your vendors (Brocade and Dell) to implement them in their software images.